# select user on create view

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `project.users` and a table `project.questions`

I have to create a view that select all the questions a user asked.
But how can I select the user in the `WHERE` clause ?

name_user is the primary key of the users table

```
CREATE VIEW project.getAllQuestions(id_question, name_user, date, text ,title) AS
SELECT qu.id_question, qu.name_user, qu.date, qu.text, qu.title
FROM project.questions qu WHERE qu.name_user= ????
ORDER BY qu.date
```

Comment: You can't.  You would do that in the outer query that references the view.

Comment: When you say 'a user' do you mean one specific user? If so just type their name in. If it's the current user, why not just execute this as a SELECT rather than creating a view? If you actually want to create a separate version of this view for every user, you'll need to generate it procedurally using PL/SQL or another language. That only really makes sense if you're going to make it a persisted view and you don't have too many users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no parameters for views — a view behaves just like a table.

Maybe a set returning function is what you want:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_user_questions(auser text) RETURNS SETOF project.questions
   LANGUAGE sql AS
'SELECT * FROM project.questions
WHERE name_user = auser';
```